# Is it financially risky to buy new car made in UK considering Brexit?

Tags: car, brexit

I live in an East-European EU country and I am considering buying a new Toyota Auris. These are made in the UK and Toyota has no plans to relocate. That makes me nervous because after Brexit,  I may have a problem due to  service components skyrocketing in price.  In the event of no deal,  is there a risk that car components made in the UK  might increase 2x or more in price?

Comment: Though I'm not familiar with that particular model, and thus can't give you a definitive answer, Toyota shares many components between models.  Those components are made around the world (it's likely that your "made in Britain" Toyota is only assembled there), by many differents suppliers, and parts should be readily available in the aftermarket.

Comment: Seems to me like the best anyone can do in trying to answer this question is to speculate. It'd probably be very hard to answer objectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reason why they changing Auris back to Corolla.

Toyota have this comfort that many of their parts are interchangeable between different models. For example clutch for Auris fit also on Corolla made in 2006, Urban Cruiser and (surprisingly) Yaris. And those parts are not made in UK.

Next is that not all parts are exclusively made by car manufacturer. For example some shocks are made by KYB. I don't remember the naming but in EU it's coded as "made in factory/manufacturer of OEM parts" (or identical with OEM).

What I would look at, rather than parts, is the fact that they going back to Corolla so 2018 Auris is the last years of this model. It may be reason for end of year sale with big rebate as dealerships will try to push them out and make room for Corollas. If you can compare prices of Auris at the beginning of this years and last year rebate for "MY 2017" models you can see difference in price.